# "Fatal: authentication failed" error when pushing to bitbucket repo

Tags: git, windows-7, bitbucket

I am trying to authenticate in windows 7 terminal : git push.
Used to work before but now i am getting :

> fatal: authentication failed for https://bitbucket.srv....

However i can login through my browsers to same repo. Is this a git issue? How to resolve?

Comment: Did you try with ssh? It may be that the server configuration has changed, so you can try with ssh:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Comment: Just tried to push from another directory same repo and it works. Do i need to generate another ssh key?

Comment: There shouldn't be need for that, Git uses the same key for all following sessions.

Answer (score 21):

Go to `Control Panel -> Credentials Manager -> Windows Credentials` and see if there's an entry for it in there. If so, remove it and attempt to `push` again. You should then be re-prompted for username and password.

[image]

Comment: This saved my day!

Comment: Nice Work -@SukanyaPai