# fatal: Authentication failed when pushing to bitbucket.org

Tags: github, bitbucket

Hi on a linux system and having a really difficult time pushing a few of my commits.
when I do git push I get this message which I then enter the password but I keep getting

```
git push
```

when I enter my password it cannot authenticate

```
fatal: Authentication failed
```

I have tried to modified my ./.git/config and entered

```
[credential]
        name = xxx
        email = xx
[user]
        name = xxx
        email = xx
```

both are the same

I also have other projects on the main github.com and that seems to work fine.
is there anything I can try?

there was a similar issue but it was on a windows box,
["Fatal: authentication failed" error when pushing to bitbucket repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586386/fatal-authentication-failed-error-when-pushing-to-bitbucket-repo)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, user/email have nothing to do with remote Git hosting server *authentication*, and are only used for local commit authorship.

Second, make sure you are using HTTPS URL (which can indeed request for credentials -- username / password or username / token), not SSH (which could require entering a passphrase to decrypt the private SSH key)

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote -v
```

Third, for HTTPS, try a [HTTPS access token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/http-access-tokens-939515499.html) instead of your actual account password.